# Autofocus para varios campos

Tags: javascript, bootstrap

Tengo un formulario login en una modal en bootstrap 4, y quiero autofocus en los campos **email** y **password**.

```
<form action="proceso.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Correo electrónico">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Contraseña">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Aceptar</button>
</form>
```

Leyendo la documentación de bootstrap. Para poner autofocus en el campo **email** utilizo esto, y funciona:

```
<script>
    $('#login').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
        $('#email').trigger('focus')
    })
</script>
```

Ahora quiero que el foco pase luego al campo **password** luego de darle ENTER, para ello agrego lo siguiente:

```
<script>
    $('#login').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
        $('#password').trigger('focus')
    })
</script>
```

Pero al cargar la página el foco aparece en el segundo campo.
Cuál es el problema?

Comment: No te sirve realizarlo por HTML con tabindex??

Comment: No. Así está el diseño.

Comment: No se puede aplicar múltiples focos en un formulario, es por eso que se le reemplaza el primer foco y solo aparece el segundo campo con foco

Comment: Entiendo que entiendes porque el foco aparece en el segundo campo, el primer script hace que al cargarse el modal, el campo "email" coja el foco, a continuación el segundo script hace lo mismo pero con el campo password, luego la ultima instrucción es que al cargarse el modal sea el campo password el que coja el foco, ahora bien entiendo que quieres que después de rellenar el campo "email", de alguna manera el foco pase al campo "pasword", pero cual es el criterio? por ejemplo después de darle a la tecla enter o cuando?

Comment: Ah, claro, luego de dar Enter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te dejo un ejemplo mas sencillo de aplicar

```js
$('#campoUser').keyup((e) => {
    if (e.key == "Enter") {
        $('#campoPassword').focus()
    }
})
```

> *Aveces es más **fácil** hacer las cosas de forma nativa*

Answer (score 0):

Es como dice Jhonatan en el comentario. El problema es que el foco no puede estar simultáneamente en ambos campos.
 - El listener del modal open debe disparar el focus en email
 - El listener de la tecla ENTER (o del submit del form, verificando que password esté vacío, o algo así) debería disparar el focus en password.

Es importante hacer preventDefault para evitar que ENTER dispare un submit no deseado